# SharePoint Online content translation

Tags: sharepoint-online, language

The company that I work for is switching from SP2010 to SP Online. I am really new to it and still learning everything. My question would be,

Is it possible to automatically translate the entire website content into other languages?

I know that it is possible if the user selects his own primary language and site will be translated to that but we will have information coming from different countries and it would be nice to translate that content into multiple languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response that I got from Microsoft

Dear Lukas

Based on out test, language of news cannot be changed in different one if another user interface. If we post a news in English, the news still shows English in UI which is in Chinese.

We really think this idea can help us improve our products, we sincerely suggest you post this idea in SharePoint UserVoice which is a specific platform for us to collect user's request.  The related team will adapt high votes idea and keep bring better using experience. Your idea may turn this feature into reality and benefit more users.

Please feel free to contact us if you need any help and we will be here all the time.

Best Regards,

Ivy

More info:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-online-entire-site-content-translation/61bdbf99-8167-4a73-ad67-854b8bd6114c

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the region or language setting SharePoint framework will be automatically translated in that particular language but all of the list column values will not changes

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-multi-language-website-da0b5614-8cf5-4905-a44c-90c2b3f8fbb6.

If you create custom SPFx then there is an option to create multilingual files in Loc filter of SPFx web-part.

Answer (score 0):

Variations would be the answer. Publishing features have to be activated on the site first, which means it is not available for modern communication sites.

Besides that, take Multiple Language User Interface (MUI) into consideration.

Here are some more posts for your reference.

[Introduction to multilingual features.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-multilingual-features-53411469-53e3-4570-95e2-3651f166174f)

[MULTILINGUAL AND MODERN SHAREPOINT.](https://joannecklein.com/2018/10/05/multilingual-and-modern-sharepoint/)

Comment: I know the MUI. It doesn't translate the news feed for example. Only thing that is translated is default sharepoint website information, like buttons, page, site settings and so on. I need to translate the content inside the news an so on

Comment: @LukasŠliužas ok then configuring Variations would suit your needs