# New web part for multiple pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, administration, multilingual

I have a modern SharePoint Hub site and the option for multiple languages is enabled for it.

When I change the layout of the site (for example: I add a new text web part on the German site) it's not visible on the English site.

Is there a solution for the automatic update of all language pages?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible using SharePoint out of the box capabilities.

> Pages are **not translated automatically**. Each page created in your default language can have a corresponding page in a chosen target language that you, or someone you assign, manually translates. After you translate such a page and publish it, it will automatically be displayed to users who prefer that language.
>
> Changes to the original, source page or to other translation pages are **not automatically synced** with all translation pages. Each translation page must be updated manually.

**Documentation**: [Create multilingual SharePoint sites, pages, and news](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-multilingual-sharepoint-sites-pages-and-news-2bb7d610-5453-41c6-a0e8-6f40b3ed750c)

---

Check below similar threads for more information:

1. [SharePoint Online content translation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/273681/sharepoint-online-content-translation)
2. [How can we automatically translate SharePoint sites into multiple languages using SharePoint Online? E.g. English to French?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/289138/how-can-we-automatically-translate-sharepoint-sites-into-multiple-languages-usin)
3. [Automatically translate pages on multilingual SharePoint sites](https://michalsacewicz.com/automatically-translate-news-on-multilingual-sharepoint-sites/)

Comment: To address your concern about the situation, we’d suggest you go to feedback on this issue, this is the best platform to let us hear from you and make our products and services better for you and others. https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/